# ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm upgrading from Rails 4 to 4.2. I have a users controller that looks something like this:

## user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  protected

  def create_with_token
    @user.attributes = params[:user]
    @user.validate_password = true

    if @user.save
      
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :more_attributes
    )
  end
end
```

I'm not sure yet if this has something to do with strong_params. But as far as I know `params[:user]` returns a hash. So why do I get `ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.` on `@user.attributes = params[:user]`?

I checked the [rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb#L28) and found:

```
def assign_attributes(new_attributes)
  if !new_attributes.respond_to?(:stringify_keys)
    raise ArgumentError, "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument."
  end
  return if new_attributes.empty?

  attributes = new_attributes.stringify_keys
  _assign_attributes(sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes))
end
```

From here, assuming `#assign_attributes` replaced `#attributes` (It's actually an [alias](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/attributes%3D) for it. I can infer that `params[:user]` is not responding to `#stringify_keys`. But why? How? What's the work around?

Comment: you should use `user_params`, but i was  expecting a `forbiddenAttributesError`

Answer (score 0):

Your `params[:user]` is an instance of ActionController::Parameters, I guess... so you just need to switch:

`@user.attributes = params[:user]`

To

`@user.attributes = user_params`